# The orthogonal complement of the null space of $A$ is equal to the range of the transpose of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Prove $N(A)^{OC} = R(A^T)$, where $()^{OC}$ means orthogonal complement and $A$ is a matrix.

I figured out $R(A^T) \subseteq N(A)^{OC}$ but I'm stuck on the other direction.

I see that if $v \in N(A)^{OC}$ then $(\forall w \text{ such that } Aw=0)(w^Tv = 0)$, but I'm having trouble showing that $v = A^Tx$ for some $x$.  I thought I could combine $Aw = 0$ and $w^Tv = 0$ but one $0$ is a vector and the other is a scalar so I'm not sure how to go about this.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  Because as is well known,  and fairly easy,  the null space is the orthogonal complement of the row space.  Put this together with the fact that the image is the column space (and the rows are the columns of the transpose).

Comment: I'm trying to prove this by explicitly finding an element $x$ such that $A^Tx  = v$.  Do you know a way to find this element?

Comment: Suppose $v$ is in the orthogonal complement of the null space.  Then $v$ is in the column space of the transpose, since it's in the row space.

Comment: So what you really need is that the row space and null space are orthogonal complements of each other.   But this follows easily from the definitions.  Try writing that out and proving it.

Comment: You said "Then $v$ is in the column space of the transpose".  This is what I'm trying to prove by finding the element explicitly.  Can you elaborate more on what the element $x$ is that satisfies the equality I asked in my question? That's what I'm trying to find.

Comment: I got that.  But if you would just notice that $N(A)^{\perp}=\operatorname{Row}A$, you would be done.  I don't have a specific $x$ for you.  But there has to be one, by the previous fact.

Comment: Actually,  let's get you that $x$.  Namely $v=y\in\operatorname {Row}A\implies v=A^tx$, for some $x$.